# Issue with "ambiguous type" in ASP.NET project

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications

I created a custom profile provider for my ASP.NET web application project, and it compiles just fine, as does the rest of the application.  However, when I run the project and execute code that calls the custom provider, I get the following error in the web browser:

> The type 'TestApp.Profiles.MyProfileProvider' is ambiguous: it could
> come from assembly 'C:\Users\tampa\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary
> ASP.NET Files\vs\6824467c\65a0bd26\App_Code.kx2-e1kh.DLL' or from
> assembly 'C:\TestApp\TestApp\TestApp\bin\TestApp.DLL'. Please
> specify the assembly explicitly in the type name.

To attempt to fix this, I deleted the temporary ASP.NET folder, AND I cleaned out the Bin folder of the project.  Still, when I try to run the code, the same error comes up.

As a final attempt, I even renamed the custom provider's class in the hopes that whatever is going on would resolve, but nothing doing - same error.

Can anyone help me understand the issue?

Answer (score 0):

So, it would seem the solution is to make sure the custom provider class is not set with the build action to "compile", but rather to "content".  Now it behaves.